# How to save a Matplotlib figure in a HTML file?

Tags: python, html, pandas, matplotlib

So I know that i can save my diagramm with

`plt.savefig('/home/pi/test.png')`

But I don't really know how to save and display my diagramm with a HTML file.
For my website it would be easier use a HTML file to display my data. So is it possible to save my diagramm in HTML and how?

If it helps here is my code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import sqlite3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

con = sqlite3.connect("/home/pi/test2.db")
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from data4 limit 79;",con)




df.plot(x = 'zeit', y = 'temp', kind ='line')
plt.savefig('/home/pi/test.png')
#plt.show()
```

I'm sorry if I did some mistakes I'm a beginner:)

Comment: can you save the image as `.png` add the image within the html? (with the <img src="path_to_img.png"> tag?)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that is not possible with matplotlib But it is possible with https://mpld3.github.io/ and specifically this function: https://mpld3.github.io/modules/API.html#mpld3.fig_to_html

```
mpld3.fig_to_html(fig, d3_url=None, mpld3_url=None, no_extras=False, template_type='general', figid=None, use_http=False, **kwargs)
Output html representation of the figure
```

Comment: Thanks but when i run my this ( `mpld3.fig_to_html(plt, d3_url=None, mpld3_url=None, no_extras=False, template_type='general', figid=None, use_http=False` ) I get the Error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'canvas'`. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: How did you define plt please share more code. You can use pastebin if it doesnt fit in a comment